# .Net generic contraint on struct types

Tags: c#, .net, generics, constraints

I am trying to create a generic class whose implementation depends on the type being an `Int32`, `Int64`, `double`, `float`, or `decimal`.

```
class Calculator<T> where T: int, double, float, decimal
```

This is not right but I'm having troubles with the syntax

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do isn't legal in C#.

Comment: seems like you should be using method overloads instead of generics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't specify a constraint on a type parameter such that it has to be one of a specified set of types, no. See [MSDN for a list of valid constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

For those particular types you could specify:

```
where T : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible,
          IComparable<T>, IEquatable<T>
```

That's likely to restrict the set *fairly* well, although it would also allow other primitive types such as `byte` and `ulong`.

Comment: I was trying to create a generic calculator class that could add, subtract, multiply and divide with specified types.  This allowed me to limit the types allowed for the Generic class.  Good answer.

Answer (score 8):

> I am trying to create a generic class whose implementation depends on the type being an Int32, Int64, double, float, or decimal.

Then it is not *generic*. A generic type is one that works the same way for all possible type arguments, like a generic queue or a generic dictionary.

"Calculator" classes are the most common scenario given for a feature like that; we get this feature request all the time. We are hypothetically considering it for a hypothetical future version of C# that has not been announced and does not exist. Doing the feature right would require considerable support from a hypothetical future version of the CLR that also has not been announced and does not exist. The scenario is not a particularly high priority as these things go, so please do not be disappointed if it does not come to pass.

There are a number of ways such a feature could be surfaced. For example, we could say that you can put static methods in interfaces. Math operators are static methods, and so then you could constrain a type parameter to be a type that implements static interface IAddable, or some such thing.

**Remember any musings Eric makes about the future of unannounced products that do not exist and might never exist is for your entertainment only.**

Comment: +1 vote for f# inline functionality. Runtime reflective creation of anything using said triggering the full c# compiler (helpfully packaged as a service by some guy you might know). Getting debugger support for even the reflective cases would be amazing. Yes I know it can be abused but damn if it's not wonderful

Comment: If I hold my breath, I wonder which would exist first: a "perfect, feature-complete" version of C#, or Half Life 3.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that. You can only do it to an interface, `class`, `struct`, or empty constructor (`new()`), or a base class.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

The closest would be `struct, IConvertable`.

One technique I have seen is to use the static constructor and throw asserts or exceptions, but this is not compile time checking, only runtime.

```
class Calculator<T>  
   where T : struct
{
   static Calculator()
   {
     Debug.Assert(typeof(T) == typeof(int), "FAIL"); //TODO: extend to other types
   }
}
```

Comment: No, you can do it for a specific class as well. For example "where T : Stream". Oh, or a type parameter.

Comment: Couldn't you get compile-time checking via the use of a a `Caclulator` factory, with method overloads only for the supported types and not giving `Calculator` a public constructor?